# What's bond between laptop battery cell quantity and mah? I need the highest possible capacity battery for Acer Aspire 7745G

Tags: laptop, battery-life, battery

I'm looking for battery for my laptop Acer Aspire 7745G. I need the largest possible capacity and for me it doesn't matter how heavy it is. As I read in Acer website, more cells means higher weight and capacity. But I didn't find explanation anywhere what's bond between mah and cells quantity. After all, mah also means battery capacity. Maybe you could also recommend me battery for Acer Aspire 7745G?(optional)

Comment: For modern, quality, commonly used 18650 cells, you can expect up to around 3.5 Ah.
At a nominal voltage of 3.7 V, that translates to just shy of 13 Wh per cell.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I probably need about 9 Ah. But I found maximum available only 7.8. Now I think, maybe better for me would be powerbank

Comment: I'd probably agree. Most manufacturers don't offer batteries over 100 Wh, since that's usually the limit you're allowed to take on planes as a single unit.
If you can afford to momentarily shut down the PC, you could just buy a bunch of batteries and keep swapping them. Some laptops even allow a very short time of operation without a battery for this, but I don't think that applies to yours.

Comment: [Here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32465588297.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.4b6f54f2sG12s7&algo_pvid=94cd49dd-6f65-4011-b79a-40836f8e3ddf&algo_expid=94cd49dd-6f65-4011-b79a-40836f8e3ddf-8&btsid=870da000-86c8-4d63-b010-b413d4cb1b2d&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3,searchweb201603_55) I found this battery for my laptop and it shows real capacity to be 6Ah and 9 cells. So, does it mean that this battery has 6x9 (54Ah)? Because, [this](https://superuser.com/questions/834679/can-a-power-bank-work-as-a-laptop-battery-alternative) says that

Comment: "Laptop batteries normally tell the capacity of an individual cell and how many cells they have", right?

Comment: The other important aspect is the voltage. The battery claims to have 6000 - 6600 mAh at 11.1V, that translates to around 66,6 Wh of energy.
What does it say on the original battery? I seem to find both 50 Wh and 99 Wh claims for the original power of a 7745G battery.